# Discrepancy between $(document).height() vs $(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to detect when an element comes into view so I can fade it in. I felt I could just detect its vertical position on the page and fade it in once the scroll value approached it.

The problem I am having is the document.height is always much larger than value of document.scrollTop()+window.height() on every page. Also the amount is variable each time (I thought this could be an issue due to a nav walker which hides the desktop menu and inserts a "burger" menu, however the amount of changes varies across pages.)

Thus:

```
document.body.scrollHeight - $(window).height() == $('body').scrollTop();
```

returns false in console log.

Has anyone come across this? I am entirely perplexed.  All floated elements are cleared. There are no elements/nodes being added nor AJAX adding dynamic content.

Thanks in advance if anyone has any theories as to what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

`document.height` is the height of the entire body tag. `$(window).height()` is the height of your browser window. The left side of your conditional subtracts the viewport from the final calculated height. That does not mean that it's equal to the scroll position of the document.

```
+ - - - - - - +    + - - - - - - +   + - - - - - - +
:             :    :             :   :  Scroll Top :
:             :    :             :   :  4 lines    :
+=============+    :             :   + - - - - - - +
| window      |    :             :  
| height      |    :   document  :  
| 5 lines     |    :   height    :  
+=============+    : - window    :   
:             :    :   height    :
:             :    :   ________  :
: document    :    :   13 lines  :
: height      :    :             :
: (offscreen) :    :             :
: 18 lines    :    + - - - - - - +
:             :
:             :
:             :
+ - - - - - - +

                     13lines != 4lines
```

Instead, try looking for `$(document).height() - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height());` to get the starting position of things below the window.

Comment: Thank you Christian! I ended up figuring out a workaround, but your answer explains this very well. I will go refactor this evening based upon your excellent explanation.